# Facebook Graph API's dialogue doesn't show image preview first time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

‎I'm using Graph API JS SDK **v2.11** and trying to share a link from my website to my Facebook profile. Now, I'm facing the same problem that Facebook has already mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) (Please search *Pre-caching images*):

I just can't see image in dialogue preview on first click. (Although image is shared successfully in my profile)

On second click, it is rendered fine. I have provided all necessary meta tags including `og:image`, `og:image:width`, `og:image:height` (according to width and heights of my images) but still it's not working!

[image]

I just can't understand why it's not working! I read same solutions on other similar questions but nothing is working. Can it be because of different origins (The image link has a sub domain)? Does anybody have any idea about it?

Here's markup for meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/views/1103/your-facebook-profile-picture-popularity/1522777597_5ac3bdfd8c524">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Know about your Facebook profile picture popularity">
<meta property="og:description" content="Example has a collection of latest fun apps. Know how much your Facebook friends care about you and find out your profile picture popularity.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://api.example.com/v1/app/images/img_1522777597_5ac8hdfd8c524.jpg">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1848969382006870">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="660">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="560">
```

Image dimensions are: Width **660px**, Height: **560px**
Image is visible to public (i.e., has all necessary permissions to *others*)

PS: I can pre-cache the image with the Facebook's Sharing Debugger, but the images are generated dynamically, so it's not possible to do it manually.